# Convert Big Decimal to String in Rails Console

Tags: count, ruby-on-rails-4, console, sum

I am trying to get my console to print out a summation of all my Locations rate card pricing.

I am trying to complete this task through the console but getting a BigDecimal as the result. Stuck on how to convert this result into a legible string or integer.

Results:

```
Location.pluck(:rate_card).sum
      => "#<BigDecimal:7f7cf347edd0,'0.3091675E6',18(36)>"
```

In my Location 'index', to be able to see a dollar amount, I have this setup as:

```
 <%= number_to_currency(location.rate_card, :precision => 2) %>
```

TIA

Answer (score 11):

```
Location.each do |e|
  puts e.rate_card.to_s.to_f.round(2)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing `:rate_card` returned as a BigDecimal because that's how it's defined in your database schema. If you were to issue `Location.rate_card.class` in a Rails console you'll see `=> BigDecimal`.

As was mentioned by @Darby, you can use `round`. In a console, issue `Location.pluck(:rate_card).sum.round(2)` and that should show the desired result rounded properly.

Lastly, is there significance to the second part of your results? You show the code you're using to display the view code properly but I don't think it has bearing on your question.

Answer (score 1):

A BigDecimal can be converted to a string like this.

```
pry(main)> b = BigDecimal.new('78.23')
=> #<BigDecimal:7ff0119cab68,'0.7823E2',18(18)>
[37] pry(main)> b.to_s
=> "0.7823E2"
```

You don't need to change this to a string first and then a float.
`to_f` is defined on a BigDecimal object.

```
[34] pry(main)> b.to_f
=> 78.23
```

There is also `to_i` and `to_r` for integers and rationals respectively.