# Why am I getting a TypeError? (no implicit conversion of String into Hash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the `number_to_currency` method in some code in a the agile web development tutorial for rails 5. I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError in Store#index
    Showing C:/Sites/depot/app/views/store/index.html.erb where line #13 raised:

no implicit conversion of String into Hash
Extracted source (around line #13):

    <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
    <div class="price_line">
      <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
      <%= button_to t('.add_html'),
      line_items_path(product_id: product, locale: I18n.locale),
      remote: true %>
```

The way I understand the error is that the number_to_currency method expects a number and is getting a string. I have checked the migration file and the product.price should be a decimal. in rails console `Product.first.price.class` gives the class `BigDecimal`. and not a String as the error suggests. And where does the Hash come into play. Why is it trying to convert a string into a hash. I am not understanding what is happening in the method. Can anyone explain this to me?

index.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1><%= t('.title_html') %></h1>


<% cache @products do %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <% cache product do %>
      <div class="entry">
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
        <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
        <div class="price_line">
          <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
          <%= button_to t('.add_html'),
          line_items_path(product_id: product, locale: I18n.locale),
          remote: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

exctracted from schema.rb

```
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

And the relevant log entry:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.11.2 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:21 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:23 +0100
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
ProductsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
ProductsChannel is streaming from products
Started GET "/orders/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:25 +0100
Processing by OrdersController#new as HTML
  Cart Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (3.0ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2018-03-30 13:06:25.693988"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-30 13:06:25.693988"]]
   (102.4ms)  commit transaction
  LineItem Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["cart_id", 35], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :ensure_cart_isnt_empty rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 446ms (ActiveRecord: 112.3ms)


Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:40 +0100
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:40 +0100
ProductsChannel stopped streaming from products
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:40 +0100
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:40 +0100
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:40 +0100
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:40 +0100
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:40 +0100
  Cart Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 35], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ProductsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
ProductsChannel is streaming from products
  Rendering store/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Product Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."title" ASC
  Rendered store/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1076.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1315ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of String into Hash):
    10:         <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
    11:         <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
    12:         <div class="price_line">
    13:           <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
    14:           <%= button_to t('.add_html'),
    15:           line_items_path(product_id: product, locale: I18n.locale),
    16:           remote: true %>

app/views/store/index.html.erb:13:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_store_index_html_erb__666600258_62743356'
app/views/store/index.html.erb:7:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_store_index_html_erb__666600258_62743356'
app/views/store/index.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_store_index_html_erb__666600258_62743356'
app/views/store/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_store_index_html_erb__666600258_62743356'
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (13.9ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (3326.8ms)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 14:06:55 +0100
ProductsChannel stopped streaming from products
```

Comment: please post the definition of method  `number_to_currency`

Comment: @GaneshNavale https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= number_to_currency(product.price.to_f) %>
```

instead of

`<%= number_to_currency(product.price) %>`

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: @Owen Could you please let me know in `product.price` what value is saving?
Please check your DB using `rails console`.

Comment: for example for the first product: irb(main):002:0> Product.first
  Product Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Product id: 2, title: "Rails, Angular, Postgres, and Bootstrap", description: "<p>\r\n      <em>Powerful, Effective, and Efficient ...", image_url: "dcbang.jpg", price: #<BigDecimal:7a1cd08,'0.5E1',9(27)>, created_at: "2018-01-14 07:03:13", updated_at: "2018-01-27 16:38:22">
irb(main):003:0>

Comment: @owen It looks your price is saving in BigDecimal and to convert it into
decimal. we use `.to_f`. Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979774/convert-big-decimal-to-string-in-rails-console

Comment: @owen Please check `Product.first.price.to_f` and put your output here.

Comment: irb(main):003:0> Product.first.price.to_f
  Product Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 5.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167878/discussion-between-akshay-borade-and-owen).